# I want to show $E(X)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(X\ge n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Let $X:\Omega \to \mathbb N$ be a random variable on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal B,P)$ .show that $$E(X)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(X\ge n).$$

my definition from $E(X)$ is equal
$$E(X)=\int_{\Omega}XdP.$$
$\mathcal B$ is Borel $\sigma $-algebra

Thanks.

I think we can write $E(X) = \sum_i x_i \cdot P(X = x_i)$.

$P( X \ge i ) = P( X = i ) + P( X = i + 1 ) + \dots$ and get summation from both side
 but this idea for discrete but in question  do not mention X is discrete or Continuous.

Comment: [Posted more than 5 hours earlier](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/76435/6633) on stats.SE where it has already received an answer.

Comment: @DilipSarwate. it answer not complete and I am Confused.if it possible for you help me to solve this question .thanks

Comment: Explained $n$ times on this very site.

Comment: @Did.ok if it possible for you give me a link about this question.I am sure you are Excellent in probabilty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $X$ is absolutely continuous since you've seen the proof in the discrete case.

Let $H=\{(e,t)\in\Omega \times \mathbb{R} : 0\leq t \leq X(e)\}$ i.e. the area under the graph.

Then $E[X]=\int_0^\infty P(X\geq t) dt$. (your equality is in this case an inequality as will be seen later).
Consider the projection functions $p_1: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \mapsto X$ and $p_2: \Omega \times \mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ then we can write
$$H=p_2^{-1}([0,\infty))\cap (f\circ p_1-p_2)^{-1}([0,\infty))$$

To see H is a $\mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable set.
Define now
$$H_x=\{t\in \mathbb{R} : (e,t) \in \mathbb{R} \}=\{t\in \mathbb{R} : 0\leq t \leq X(e) \}=[0,X(e)]$$
and
$$ H^t=\{e\in \Omega : (e,t)\in H \}=\{f\geq t\}$$
if $t\geq 0$ and the empty set otherwise (remember this to when we insert it in a second).

Now ($\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure) using [this rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure)
$$P\otimes\lambda(H)=\int_\Omega \lambda(H_x) dP=\int_\Omega \lambda([0,X(e)]) dP=\int_\Omega X(e) dP=E[X]$$
Duh, but doing it the other way around yields
$$P\otimes\lambda(H)=\int_R P(H^t) dt=\int_0^\infty P(X\geq t) dt$$
So $$\int_0^\infty P(X\geq t) dt = E[X]$$
Since $t\mapsto P(X\geq t)$ is decreasing it is measurable and the mentioned inequality
$$E[X]\geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X\geq k )$$
follows directly from the observation that for $t\in(0,\infty)$
$$P(X\geq t)\geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X\geq k)1_{(k-1,k]}(t)$$
integrating it and interchanging sum and integration.